# symfony: queries inside a callback constraint?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Im reading the doc about [Callback constraints](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html), but ..is it possible to run a query to check persisted data? is it advisable? if not, what should be the way?

Comment: It's possible; take a look at UniqueEntityValidator from Doctrine 2 Bridge: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Validator/Constraints/UniqueEntityValidator.php